# Check if a number exists in between a set of two numbers in another file and return output accordingly in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

## To elaborate more on the question, please see my exact requirement description:

Contents of Input File1 (input1.txt):

```
1
5
7
11
```

Contents of Input File2 (input2.txt):

```
3
9
```

Now, I need a loop that goes to the first input file, takes the first two elements (i.e.1 and 5) and then checks if there is any number in between 5 and 7 in the second file. In this case, there is a number (i.e 3 ) so it returns 'good' and in the second iteration, it picks up (5 and 7 from 1st imput) compares with the list in second file and this time as there is no match, it should return 'bad'.

Expected output:

```
good
bad
good
```

I have written a code that is able to read the inputs of first file in sets of two.
So, I am able to read 1 and 5, 5 and 7 in the loop and so on but I am not able to find an appropriate code that compares any number in between in the entire input2 file and return output accordingly .

```
last=`wc -l input1.txt|awk -F ' ' '{printf $1}'`
for ((i=1;i<$last;i++))
do 
x=$i
y=`expr $x+1`
a=`sed -n "${x}p" input1.txt`
b=`sed -n "${y}p" input1.txt`
#code is working correctly till above line
while read line
if [ "$a" -le "$line" ]&&[ "$b" -le "$line" ]; then
echo "good" >> output.txt
else
echo "bad" >> output.txt
fi
done < input2.txt
done
```

Output for this code is:

```
good
bad
bad
bad
bad
good
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {v2[$1]; next} 
    FNR>1 {
        result="bad"
        for (v in v2) 
            if (0+prev < 0+v && 0+v < 0+$1) {result="good"; break}
        print result
    } 
    {prev=$0}
' input2.txt  input1.txt
```

The `0+variable` is needed to force numeric comparisons, otherwise awk considers the string "9" lexicographically greater than the string "11".

bash, same logic. Numeric comparison is enforced with `(( ... ))`

```
v1=( $(<input1.txt) )
v2=( $(<input2.txt) )
for ((i=1; i<${#v1[@]}; i++)); do 
    result=bad
    for v in "${v2[@]}"; do 
        if (( ${v1[i-1]} < v && v < ${v1[i]} )); then 
            result=good
            break
        fi
    done
echo $result
done
```

Ruby is nice and concise. Have to be careful here too that we treat the values as integers, not strings

```
ruby -e '
  v1 = File.readlines(ARGV.shift).collect {|line| line.to_i}
  v2 = File.readlines(ARGV.shift).collect {|line| line.to_i}
  v1.each_cons(2) {|(a,b)| puts v2.any? {|v| a<v && v<b} ? "good" : "bad"}
' input1.txt input2.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Glenn. It worked fine. I took in bash logic.